# Cannot convert from BasicCookieStore to CookieStore

Tags: android, http, cookies, mismatch

I am going to use cookies in my application so I don`t have to re-login for each requst I make to the server. Further on I have been looking on examples, and it seems that this is done in each of them:

```
CookieStore mCookieStore  = new BasicCookieStore();
```

However, when I try to do this I only get the error:

`Cannot convert from BasicCookieStore to CookieStore`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you import the wrong java class.

The correct ones:

```
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
```

not

```
import java.net.CookieStore;
```

[BasicCookieStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicCookieStore.html) implements [CookieStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html). You should be able to convert from BasicCookieStore to CookieStore.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution asap and give feedback :)